# sh: 39: unzip: not found while installing deno

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, deno

I am getting this following error `sh: 39: unzip: not found` while installing Deno on windows Subsystem For Linux(WSL).

Answer (score 8):

I have solved this issue by installing unzip on my Ubuntu by running `sudo apt-get install unzip`

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by doing

```
sudo apt-get install unzip -y
```

and was fixed

refer here https://github.com/denoland/deno_install#unzip-is-required

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is simply install unzip by `sudo apt-get install unzip`.